# How to use positive lookahead for a specific word in apache regex

Tags: regex, apache, regex-lookarounds

How to use positive lookahead for a specific word in apache regex.

Example:

In java regex i have the following regex `^(?=.*\bLOCAL\sSERVICE\b)`.

What is the equivalent regex in apache regex? Is there any positive lookahead in apache regex which is equivalent for `?=`

Answer (score 1):

**In short: Apace uses the PCRE regex engine, which is one of the most full-featured engines out there. You can use the same lookahead you are used to in Java.**

There are slight differences, but they shouldn't matter for your pattern.

**For reference: token-by-token comparison of your pattern in Java and PCRE**

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) `(?=.*\bLOCAL\sSERVICE\b)`

  - Java 8 interprets this part differently `.*`

    - Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) `.*`

      - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - PCRE 8.34–8.35 UTF-32 interprets this part differently `.*`

    - Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) `.*`

      - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - Java 8: Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) `\b`
  - PCRE 8.34–8.35 UTF-32: Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore) `\b`
  - Match the character string “LOCAL” literally (case sensitive) `LOCAL`
  - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) `\s`
  - Match the character string “SERVICE” literally (case sensitive) `SERVICE`
  - Java 8: Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) `\b`
  - PCRE 8.34–8.35 UTF-32: Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore) `\b`

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I am using jakarta-regexp-1.5 with "java6". Could you please tell me there is any equivalent positive lookahead available in apache regex. If it is available can you give me the equivalent regex.

Comment: @user3701639 In case my answer wasn't clear, YES. The regex pattern is the exact same. There is no difference at all in the regex you need to use with Apache. :)

Comment: If it is the same why i am getting the following exception when i try to run   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.regexp.RESyntaxException: Syntax error: Missing operand to closure
 at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.terminal(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.closure(Unknown Source)
 What i need to correct in the regex if i use this in apache regex